# wifi network disappears after connecting

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I just upgraded to ubuntu 13.10, i did a fresh install, and now when i connect to my home wifi network, it disconnects me shortly after connecting, and then I can no longer see my network in the list of available connections. It was working perfectly under 13.04, so im pretty certain that this is not an issue with my home network itself or my router. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure either.  I was looking for an answer to a similar question.  My wireless is disappearing after about 10 hours and I can't restore it minus restarting.  In your situation; do a `ifconfig -a` and see if the WiFi interface is even there at all.  If it is not then it likely the driver for it wasn't compiled for it or is not loading for some reason.

You can also do a `lspci -v` to see if the device and driver are linked.  In my case I see this:

```
0d:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52
    Memory at c4500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

If you notice my kernel driver is "iwlwifi" in this example. You can also check /var/log/udev, /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log for indications to why it didn't load.
```